Webpack: No loaders are configured to process this file in Custom React js lib
I am creating a custom react js lib. when running this lib locally with a next js sample project i am getting

../src/components/Calendar/CalendarSelector.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (230:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders


Below is my project overall structure. I have also added webpack file.

Import the file in index.js sample next js project
import { MuiDynaTable } from '../../../src/index';


Webpack.config.js file
module.exports = {
    // Other webpack configuration...
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

rollup.config.mjs

import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image'; // Import the image plugin

export default {
    input: 'src/index.js', // Update this path to your library's entry point
    output: {
        file: 'dist/bundle.js', // Update this path to your desired output file
        format: 'umd', // Universal Module Definition (UMD)
        name: 'mui-dynatable', // Name of your library (optional)
        globals: {
            react: 'React', // External dependencies (optional)
            'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        babel({
            exclude: 'node_modules/**',
            babelHelpers: 'bundled' // Use 'bundled' for Rollup
        }),
        resolve(),
        commonjs({
            include: /node_modules/,
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'] // Include JSX files
        }),
        postcss({
            extract: true, // Extract CSS to a separate file
            modules: true // Enable CSS modules (optional)
        }),
        image(), // Add the image plugin
        terser() // Minify the bundle (optional)
    ],
    external: ['react', 'react-dom'] // Specify external dependencies (optional)
};


Next js project config

module.exports = {
    output: 'export',

    images: {
        unoptimized: true
    },

    webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
        // Add SVG loader
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.svg$/,
            use: ['@svgr/webpack']
        });

        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            include: /node_modules\/mui-dynatable/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
                }
            }
        });

        if (!isServer) {
            config.externals.push(/static\/fonts\/.*$/);
        }

        return config;
    }
};


You're showing everything except for the thing that matters: webpack is explicitly telling you that there's something wrong on line 230 in CalendarSelector.js that makes your file invalid JS. As a result, webpack can't load it using its own loaders. So: what's on that line?

its a box from mui lib @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans
https://github.com/parmarravi/mui-dynatable/tree/dev my repo

No: please [edit] your post, and talk about what's in that file, on that line. If people need to go to your repo just to get the details necessary to help, that's a bad post, so add those details here. There is something "illegal" in your file, so you now get to investigate that.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i have modified my post. Let me know if still things are missing in the post

it looks like it's tripping over that <Box> suggesting that despite the part of your webpack config that you're showing, it's not actually using the jsx loader to load your file, so it may be time to start reducing your project to a [mcve], and in the process of throwing away all the complexity, hopefully find the problem (but if not, you'll have a really small section of code to show off in your post at least)

even after adding only div tags it give the same error. I have commented everything. Am i missing any webpack config?? @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

No idea, so it's time to properly run through the [mcve] exercise. Which isn't just "replace tags" but "remove nearly everything that doesn't contribute to the problen", including trimming your entire codebase to "your app is a single tag, to the file that's going wrong", and build-configs stripped down to the absolute basics (no assets, no css, etc. etc. just enough to build the JSX side of things). And you keep removing and removing until you've reach the limits of what you can remove. (which is basically 2 files, and one config) and then if things STILL fail, that's can go in your post.
